# Open document from another database

Tags: xpages

I'm displaying a view and associated documents on an xpage, however the view and documents are coming from another database. The view displays fine, but when I try to open a document in the view I get Error 404 HTTP Web Server: Item Not Found Exception. I'm pretty certain I know the issue, but looking for idea's around it.

The view is dynamic, and I tell it which view to open by passing in a custom property - The view has the setting to open document using xpage associated with he documents form. This works perfectly, as all forms in my database have the option set to display xpage on web access.

I *think* my issue, is that I although I have an xpage in my database to display the form, the form is located in another database, which is legacy, no xpage design at all, so when I try to set the display xpage on web access, I cannot choose the xpage from my database as it doesn't exist in this database.

I can't just put the xpage from database A into database B as it errors due to all the dependencies required that are not part of database B, so just wondered if anyone has worked around this before?

Thanks

I haven't added any code as I don't think its required, but if you need any, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best option is rather than using the in-built link option on your view component to point to the document and use the Form to determine the XPage, to add a Link control and build up the relevant URL to point to the XPages and set the relevant documentId, e.g. "myXPage?documentId=A45e". `action` can be set to "openDocument" if needed. I'm not sure if you'll need to pass the `databaseName` or if it can be set on the datasource alone.

With a Data View, it's easy to just use the summary facet instead of pointing to a column. With a View Panel, you'll need to set the `var` property on the View Panel itself and paste the Link control into the relevant column.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for this, the issue I have however is we have lots of legacy applications and I am developing a bootstrap database and creating lots of drag and drop custom controls. In regards the views, I have built a dynamic view custom control, where, in its simplest form, all we need to do is pass a view name, and it renders the view as required as there are hundreds of views and forms. With your approach I would need to create lots of checks to see what the form is to then tell it which xpage to display, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Adding a blank XPage with the same name to the target database may allow you to set the XPageAlt field on the Form so it points to the correct XPage name. That may work, I don't know. It depends whether the XPages runtime then uses the XPage name relative to the current XPage design NSF, or points to the XPage in the data NSF. I'm not sure if I've ever tested that.

Comment: I'll give it a go this afternoon and feedback! Thanks

Comment: Hi Paul, your answer wasn't what resolved this for me, it was actually your comment however I cannot mark that as the correct answer so have accepted the original.....

I didnt need to touch the legacy app at all...I had already copied the form from legacy app into xpage app to use for my data binding on my xpage so it seems all I needed to do was give my xpage the same name as the form, and it now displays the information from the legacy app within my xpage app. Cheers